# How to get pass "The site's security certificate is not trusted!" while monitoring URLs in powershell

Tags: powershell, ssl, powershell-3.0

I am using a powershell script that checks a web URL to see if it exists.  However, a couple of sites I have to check redirect you to a site that needs you to click a button to proceed.  Even though the site is running, it returns failure because of the page beforehand.  Is there a way to get around this using powershell script?  The error I receive is below followed by my code.

**Error**

SSL Error Icon
The site's security certificate is not trusted!
You attempted to reach , but the server presented a certificate issued by an entity that is not trusted by your computer's operating system. This may mean that the server has generated its own security credentials, which Chrome cannot rely on for identity information, or an attacker may be trying to intercept your communications.
You should not proceed, especially if you have never seen this warning before for this site.

**Code**

```
$URLListFile = "\url_list.txt"  
$URLList = Get-Content $URLListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
$Result = @() 

#$OutputReport = "<html><title>PROD Monitoring Report</title><body><h2>PROD Monitoring         Report</h2><table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr>Description</tr><tr>Status Code</tr><tr>Status</tr><tr>Response Time</tr>";
$OutputReport += "<HTML><TITLE>PROD Report</TITLE><BODY><font color=""#99000""><H2> PROD Monitoring Report </H2></font><Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><TR bgcolor=gray><TD><B>Description</B></TD><TD><B>Code</B></TD><TD><B>Status</B></TD><TD><B>ResponseLength</B></TD></TR>"

Foreach($Uri in $URLList) 
{ 
    $startTime = Get-Date
    $req = [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($Uri)
    try 
    {
            $res = $req.GetResponse()
    } 
    catch [System.Net.WebException] 
    {
            $res = $_.Exception.Response
    }
    $endTime = Get-Date

    $OutputReport += "<tr><td>"+$Uri+"</td>";
    #$OutputReport += "<tr><td>Template</td>";
    $web_status = [int]$res.StatusCode
    if ($web_status -ne 200)
    {
            $OutputReport += "<td>"+$web_status+"</td><td bgcolor=red>Failure</td>"
    }
    else
    {
            $OutputReport += "<td>"+$web_status+"</td><td>Success</td>"
    }
    $OutputReport += "<td>"+($endTime - $startTime).TotalSeconds+" seconds</td></tr>"
} 

$OutputReport += "</table></body></html>";
$Outputreport | out-file C:\Users\phall\Desktop\Docs\report.html 

#Invoke-Expression C:\Scripts\Test.htm
```

Comment: Are you using a self-signed certificate on those servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using a self-signed certificate on those websites, you will have to install those certificates into the certificate store on the system(s) running your script, such that all users have access to them. See [this page](http://www.sqlservermart.com/HowTo/Windows_Import_Certificate.aspx) for an example.

The above has nothing to do with PowerShell, the below does.

Since you're using PowerShell 3.0, you should know about the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet. It can speed up your script quite a bit by allowing you to easily invoke an HTTP `HEAD` request, which will just tell you that your URL is alive and kicking - without having to pull *everything* sent back to the client.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -uri $uri -method HEAD |select-object statuscode
```